Type Object cannot be safely cast to HashMap<Object, Object>
I get this error and I'm confused to why and how I can fix it.
"Type Object cannot be safely cast to HashMap<Object, Object>" at "inputObject instanceof HashMap<Object, Object>"
private void readCache() {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream objectStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(cacheFile));
            
            Object inputObject = objectStream.readObject();
            
            objectStream.close();
            
            if(inputObject instanceof HashMap<Object, Object>) {
                cache = (HashMap<Object, Object>) inputObject;
            }else {
                throw new CacheException("wrong cache type");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            throw new CacheException(e);
        }
        
    }

I was trying to read a HashMap<Object,Object> from a file. I was expecting this to do the work.

Due to type erasure (docs.oracle.com), we cannot check the generic types while casting. --- Is this an error, or "just" a code style warning from your IDE?

@Turing85 Nope, it's an error on compiletime. I edited the question to make it clearer.

The problem is that generics are a figment of the compiler's imagination: At runtime, any instance has no idea what its own generics are. hence, instanceof Map is fine, but instanceof Map<Object, Object> is not. You can ask an object 'are you a map?' and it can answer. You cannot ask it 'are you a Map<Object, Object>' because it doesn't know.
Javac will let you write it, but it's a programmer assertion once you write the cast. Thus, this:
if(inputObject instanceof HashMap) {
  cache = (HashMap<Object, Object>) inputObject;
} else {
  throw new CacheException("wrong cache type");
}

Will 'work' but will generate a warning, because that <Object, Object> part is a programmer assertion. You're telling the compiler there: Trust me. I know it is. Because neither the compiler nor the run time has any way to verify that this is in fact, true. You can save a Map<String, InputStream> and it will succeed here.
The one thing you can do is Map<?, ?> instead. That is okay: ? in generics means 'I do not know', so, read map = (Map<?, ?>) someVal; as:
"Check that this someVal expression points at an object whose type is a Map that maps with keys of type 'Do Not Know' to values of type 'Do Not Know'".
Objects can answer that question perfectly well. It knows if it is a Map or not (because objects know their own generics-less type), and while they don't know their own generics, they can trivially answer yes to 'do you map who-knows-whats to whatsits?' - sure, yeah.
You can still invoke .get(anyObj) on a Map<?, ?>, and it'll return an expression of type Object. It can do that, because all types are objects, therefore, a map whose values are typed 'I do not know', will, at least, be Objects.
Hence, you could do this:
Map<?, ?> cache = ...;

if (inputObject instanceof HashMap) {
  cache = (HashMap<?, ?>) inputObject;
} else {
  throw new CacheException("wrong cache type");
}

but you probably do not want to. The problem with a Map of who knows what to some unknown type is that while you can call .get() on it just fine, no .put call can possibly be made on it, except with the null literal, and only because the null literal is every type at once, and is the only expression in all of java that has that property.
After all, given that it is a map whose key type is unknown, it may not be correct to put, say, a string in it. After all, what if your variable of type Map<?, ?> is pointing at an object of type HashMap<Integer, Integer>? Then putting a string in there would break things!
There's no way to dodge this warning - just accept it / use @SuppressWarnings to suppress it. That, or redesign it all: Instead of using a hashmap, write:
class MyCache extends HashMap<Object, Object> {}

and serialize that. Now there's no problem and no warning. Or, use existing cache solutions (such as guava), or use different serialization mechanisms.

I must disagree.  There are no legitimate uses for @SuppressWarnings.  Why not something like cache = new HashMap<Object, Object>((Map<?, ?>) inputObject);?

Of course there are legitimate uses. Anytime code warns for a situation that a human brain can trivially determine cannot possibly occur. Your suggestion causes a pointless copy operation which probably isn't performance-wise relevant, but it might be.

I have yet to encounter a @SuppressWarnings usage in application code that couldn’t be avoided with fairly little effort.
